# python automatic re-accessing without changing cookie

Tags: python, html, cookies

I have a problem with accessing specific web site.
The Web site automatically redirect to Check Page which is displaying "check your Browser"
The Check page returns HTTP 503 errors in first time.
Then web browser(chrome, IE etc) automatically re-access again.
Finally I can get into web site.

The problem is I want to access to site in Python.
So I use urllib and urllib2 both.

```
u = urllib.open(url)
print u.read()
```

Same with urllib2, but it doesn't work raising 503 error.
urllib also get HTTP 503 code but it doesn't raise error.

So I need to re-access without changing cookie

```
u = urllib.open(url)
u = urllib.open(url) ## cookie is changed
print u.read()
```

Simply I tried to call open function twice. But cookie is changed and it doesn't work
(Check Page Again)

So I use urllib2 with cooklib

```
import os.path
cj = None
ClientCookie = None
cookielib = None

import cookielib
import urllib2
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()

if os.path.isfile('cookie.lpw'):
    cj.load('cookie.lpw')

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

theurl = url
txdata = None
txheaders = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'}

req = urllib2.Request(theurl, txdata, txheaders)
handle = urllib2.urlopen(req) ## error raised
```

Error Code Here

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    handle = urlopen(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

Simply I want to re-access the site when got HTTP 503 error without change cookies.
But I don't know how to do it.
Somebody help me please.